# How to apply nodes to object

Tags: workflow

I'm new to Blender. I've created a planet and as I created each node I saw the change in the planet happen immediately. After restarting Blender I can't see the results of the nodes anymore, the planet is just grey. How can I get back to the visual mode (sorry not sure what the mode is called). Here's what I see:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are in *Solid* mode (Blender will automatically switch back to *Solid* when you'll start), switch to *Material* or *Rendered* mode by clicking on the icons on the top right or press <kbd>Z</kbd> for the pie menu.

[image]

Comment: super star! :). Thanks very much.